# can not debug mvc4 project in VS2012

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have an internet app project in mvc4. when I press the F5 key, VS start debugging. However when the browser starts, it waits and waits and waits... No exception, No error, ... It just worked fine, until I add a linq-to-entities query in one of my views.

I checked with both chrome and ie 10. nothing changed.

How can I find out where is the problem?

tanx

Comment: Can you comment out the line that you added and try again?

Comment: after adding this query: `var pics = from pic in db.PersonnelInCourses
                       where pic.PersonnelID == User.Identity.Name &&
                        pic.Course.TitleID == c.TitleID &&
                        pic.Course.BeginDate.Substring(0, 4) == PersianDateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
                       select pic;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reset your visual studio settings and try once again.

Comment: I did that. no changes... settings? what settings?

Comment: Goto Tools->ImportandExportSettings->Reset all setting and then select web development for next step.